# Basic Hibernate Select all Syntax

Tags: java, database, hibernate, exception, jpa

I am trying to retrieve data from my database with hibernate but it keeps throwing an exception

> 2012-11-11 11:35:45,943 [main] ERROR
>   com.storage.hibernate.DatabaseAccessRequestsImpl - there was an error
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

```
@Override
public List<Trade> requestPeriod() {
    List<Trade> trades = null;
    EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = manager.createQuery("from trade"); 
    try{
        trades = query.getResultList();
    }
    catch(PersistenceException e){
        logger.error("there was an error " + e);
    }
    catch(SQLGrammarException e){
        logger.error("there was an error " + e);
    }
    return trades;
}
```

I am guessing the syntax I am using for `select all` is incorrect but after looking around I can not see an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Write complete code of `EntityManager` also

Comment: it should be _"from Trade"_ (uppercase T) if Trade is the name of the mapped class

Comment: @guido this indeed was the correct answer - thank you so much

Comment: @guido: please turn your comment into an answer. I added a bit of more details, but the credit should go to you. *SkyR*, please do not accept my answer, I wasn't first :-).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz thanks, I just added a comment because it could have been just a typo

Comment: Actually, @guido didn't mention the need for " t" on the end, which is what was the problem causing a grammar exception (having a bad entity name would get a `QuerySyntaxException: trade is not mapped`).

Comment: Hmm. Except for me, with Hibernate 4.1.4, "from Trade" works fine, even without the " t". A mystery remains here ...

Comment: @TomAnderson that's actually something that only happens using JPA over hibernate I think. Minimal JPQL query would also include SELECT (_SELECT e FROM Entity [AS] e_); but something just like "from Class" is valid in HQL and (mistakenly? I think so) works in hibernate's JQPL.

Comment: @guido: Ah yes, that's possible. In any case, you're right, it's not standard JPQL, so we shouldn't worry too much about it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be `"from Trade"` (uppercase T) as Trade is the name of the mapped class.

Answer (score 6):

Note that in JPA QL `SELECT` clause is mandatory, as per: [*10.2.1.1. JPQL Select Statement*](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select):

> A select statement is a string which consists of the following clauses:
>
> - a SELECT clause, which determines the type of the objects or values to be selected;
> - a FROM clause, which provides declarations that designate the domain to which the expressions specified in the other clauses of the query apply;
>
> [...]
>
> In BNF syntax, a select statement is defined as:
>
> ```
> select_statement ::= select_clause from_clause [where_clause] [groupby_clause] [having_clause] [orderby_clause]
> ```

The bare `from Trade` syntax is Hibernate-specific, to be specification compliant you should always use:

```
select t from Trade t
```

Comment: This helped me in selecting all values from one table and none from another. Big Thank You!